# How to make a class object a checking condition in C++?

Tags: c++, boost

Boost has something like this:

```
void OnAccept( const boost::system::error_code & ec)
{
        if( ec )
        {
         ...
        }
}
```

`error_code` is a class. What operator to override to make a class object

Comment: Sorry you what now? "to make a class object"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the [safe bool idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Safe_bool). This protects from most pitfalls that occur when you simply provide a conversion to `bool`.

To provide some context: If a type can be implicitly converted to `bool` through `operator bool() const`, a value of that type can be used in comparison expressions where this conversion doesn't make any sense. The C++11 solution would be an explicit conversion operator.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the bool conversion operator for your class:

```
operator bool() const
```

Comment: Or rather use the [safe bool idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Safe_bool).

Comment: Why does he need this? For what purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Well, basically you simple could overload "operator bool()" to allow for an automatic conversion into a boolean context.

Another suggestion would be to automatically convert to a void* (operator void*()), as "there aren't that many things you can do with a void* except test it in Boolean contexts."[1]

However, the simple solution - although it might work in your specific context - is not quite free from pitfalls. I would suggest reading

[1] http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html

as it provides a throughout discussion (and solution) on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

You should make use of the cast operator.

I'm providing here a brief example.

```
#include <iostream>
class A
{
public:
    A(bool x) : _value(x)
    {}

    // cast operator for bool value
    operator bool() const
    {
        return _value;
    }

private:
    bool _value;
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    A a(true);

    if (a) { // true
        std::cout << "true" << std::endl;
    } else { //false
        std::cout << "false" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As already answered, use safe bool idiom plus consider implementing :

```
bool operator!() const;
```

that would return opposite value.

And this is exactly what boost::system::error_code does:

```
typedef void (*unspecified_bool_type)();
static void unspecified_bool_true() {}

operator unspecified_bool_type() const  // true if error
{ 
  return m_val == 0 ? 0 : unspecified_bool_true;
}

bool operator!() const  // true if no error
{
  return m_val == 0;
}
```